# 2D array size in bytes

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, byte

I would like to know, how to calculate 2D array's size in bytes.

Array: int data[][5] = {{1, 2, 3}, {0}, {4, 3, 2}};

And how should I calculate the size of this array in bytes.

Programming language is C.

Comment: Since each row consists of 5 `int` values, and there are three rows initialized, the size reported by `sizeof(data)` will be `3 * 5 * sizeof(int)`, which is almost certainly 60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) operator. The expression `sizeof data` will give you the size of the array, in bytes.

Here is a short demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int data[][5] = {{1, 2, 3}, {0}, {4, 3, 2}};

    printf( "The size of the array is: %zu\n", sizeof data );
}
```

In my test environment, this program has the following output:

```
The size of the array is: 60
```

The size of the array may be different on different platforms, but on most modern platforms, `sizeof(int)` is `4`, so the array's total size is  `4 * 3 * 5`, which is `60`.